# Convert Init function from Objective-C to Swift as short as possible

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a `init` function that written in Objective-C

**Objective-C**

```
@interface MyCustomClassInObjectiveC: NSObject

- (instancetype)initWithFirst:(NSInteger)first AndSecond: (NSInteger)second withThird:(NSInteger)third;

@end
```

And when I call it in Swift, it display all `first`, `second`, `third`

**Swift**

```
let callInSwift = MyCustomClassInObjectiveC(first: 1, andSecond: 2, withThird: 3)
```

**What I want**

I want to find some tips or anything else, that change my Objective-C code to make my Swift call as short as possible (**no `first`, `second`, `third` in Swift call)**, like this

```
let callInSwift = MyCustomClassInObjectiveC(1, 2, 3)
```

or

```
let callInSwift = MyCustomClassInObjectiveC(1, and: 2, with: 3)
```

Comment: you can do like this func test(_ first: Int, and second: Int, with third: Int)

Comment: you can do like this func test(_ first: Int, _ second: Int, _ third: Int)

Comment: You can do this by using `NS_SWIFT_NAME` macro. Check answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51744116/4061501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
-(instancetype)init:(NSInteger)first :(NSInteger)second :(NSInteger)third;
```

And call will look like

```
let callInSwift = MyCustomClassInObjectiveC(1, 2, 3)
```

//

Other alternative

```
-(instancetype)init:(NSInteger)first  and: (NSInteger)second  with:(NSInteger)third;
```

so you can use

```
let callInSwift = MyCustomClassInObjectiveC(1, and: 2, with: 3)
```

Comment: Thank you. I did it

Answer (score 2):

First solution:

```
class MyCustomClassInSwift: NSObject {

    init(_ first: Int, _ second: Int, _ third: Int) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

You can call that like this:

```
let myCustomObject = MyCustomClassInSwift(1, 2, 3)
```

Second Solution:

```
class MySecondCustomClassInSwift: NSObject {

    init(_ first: Int, and second: Int, with third: Int) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

You can call the second solution like this:

```
let mySecondCustomObject = MySecondCustomClassInSwift(1, and: 2, with: 3)
```

Care: You need to `import Foundation` if you want to use `NSObject`

Comment: Thanks. But I want to change code in Objective-C, not Swift

Answer (score 1):

Change your **obj-c code** with below

```
- (instancetype)initWithFirst:(NSInteger)first and: (NSInteger)second with:(NSInteger)third;
```

Comment: Note : this will give **MyCustomClassInObjectiveC(first: 1, and: 2, with: 3)**

Answer (score 1):

### You can use `NS_SWIFT_NAME` macro.

```
- (instancetype)initWithFirst:(NSInteger)first AndSecond: (NSInteger)second withThird:(NSInteger)third
   NS_SWIFT_NAME(init(first:second:third:));
```

This can called as:

```
MyCustomClassInObjectiveC(first: 1, second: 2, third: 3)
```

For more information read: [Advanced ObjC <-> Swift Interoperability](https://academy.realm.io/posts/altconf-nikita-lutsenko-objc-swift-interoperability/)

Answer (score 0):

for your knowledge if you use '_' before argument in method then that argument name not appear at call time. Only value need to pass.

```
func initWith(_ first: 1, _ andSecond: 2, _ withThird: 3)
{}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I want to change my Objective-C code